# How connect to Excel from Visio and display worksheet names on rectangles and list one row content on the side of corresponding rectangle?

Tags: excel, vba, visio

I'm trying to create a Diagram in Visio where I can have as many rectangles as worksheets on an excel workbook and then assign the name of each worksheet to each rectangle then I need to be able to list the content of my connections row on the side of the corresponding rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean by "connections row"?

Comment: Sorry I mean I want to display the content of the third column on the worksheet I'm connected to I named the column connections

Comment: Can you show us what has been done so far? You can access the Excel Object-model by adding it to your references (Tools-->References--> Microsoft Excel XX.X Object Library) or use the Rubberduck Reference Explorer(http://rubberduckvba.com/).  

Then you only have to open the file in question, drop a shape for every worksheet in the excel file and add some text to your shape. Maybe you could make your own shape/master with the text-field already in the right position.

Comment: Thanks I'm able to connect create a shape and list one of the column rows on the side of the object but I need all rows in the column this is the part of vba that draws the rectangle and pulls one of the rows from the column

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the code you are having problems with? I urge you to read SO's guidelines on asking question ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ). Following them makes it easier for other users to help you, properly asked questions will also be more likely to be answered.